# How can I parse several differently structured websites with the same spider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

All the websites I want to parse are in the same domain but all look very different and contain different information I need.
My start_url is a page with a list containing all links I need. So in the parse() method I yield a request for each of these links and in parse_item_page I extract the first part of the information I need - which worked completely fine.
My problem is: I thought I could just do the same another time and for each link on my item_page call parse_entry. But I tried so many different versions of this and I just can't get it to work. They are the correct URLs but scrapy seems to just don't want to call a third parse() function, nothing in there ever gets executed.

How can I get scrapy to use parse_entry, or pass all these links to a new spider?

This is a simplified, shorter version of my spider class:

```
    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        for href in response.xpath("//listItem/@href"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item_page)


    def parse_item_page(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div"):
            item = items.FirstItem()
            item['attribute'] = sel.xpath("//h1/text()").get().strip()
            for href in response.xpath("//entry/@href"):
                yield response.follow(href.extract(), callback=self.parse_entry)
            yield item


    def parse_entry(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//textBlock"):
            item = items.SecondItem()
            item['attribute'] = sel.xpath("//h1/text()").get().strip()
            yield item
```

Comment: Is `parse_item_page` executed? Is `response.xpath("//div")` non-empty? Is `href in response.xpath("//entry/@href")` non empty? Also, a note: your nested loop is iterating `response` when you probably meant `sel`, and uses an XPath that starts with `//` where you probably meant `.//`

Comment: Yes, `parse_item_page` is executed and both `response.xpath("//div")` and `href in response.xpath("//entry/@href")` are non-empty. Regarding your note: I don't think that it's supposed to be `sel` because I really wanted to open these entries on their own page (which exist).

Comment: Use `logger.debug` or `print` to check what `response.xpath("//entry/@href")` returns. It will return the same in every loop. Is that on purpose?